# Any good utilities for upgrading Kernel for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, updates

I need to update my kernel in Xenial Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Existing solutions appear to be outdated or don't work.

(**Reason:** Blender 2.90.x isn't running due to old display drivers. To update display drivers it's recommended to first upgrade the kernel.)

I've tried installing the Mainline utility,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

This results in an error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mainline
```

Has the repository for Mainline changed or are there any other good packages out there for managing kernels? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: 16.04 will be coming to end of support soon(next year), have you thought about just upgrading to 18.04?

Comment: Yes, I have a partition with Ubuntu 18.04 installed, but I have other needs and good reasons for sticking to 16.04 that I won't go into.

Comment: Upgrade from what kernel?  Are you using the GA kernel (4.4) or have you already enabled HWE and thus using the HWE of 4.15 kernel?  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Comment: The PPA ppa:cappelikan/ppa provides NO support for Xenial; 16.04/Xenial is approaching EOL and only 'main' packages are now supported (3 years of support for *flavors* and 'universe' packages unless specifically mentioned otherwise). That PPA only supports bionic (18.04) & newer which you should have noticed in your 3rd party security checks prior to adding (PPAs are 3rd party so security checks are on you).

Comment: @guiverc I have 4.4 wanting to upgrade to at least 4.15. I installed the HWE per the answer below, but that caused two problems: (1) 4.15 doesn't boot (I'm still trying to figure out why) and now I have to revert to 4.4 to use that partition. (2) HWE messed up my multi-boot GRUB, which I'm still working on fixing.

Comment: if you enable HWE and install only; you'll have both 4.4 (GA kernel) & 4.15 (HWE kernel) so can select them at boot (through grub), even make the 4.4 the default.  I would likely test a 16.04.7 ISO using *live* to see if it boots, if that does & is stable, it's likely a config on your machine & not the kernel (*assuming you validate ISO & write to media of course*)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the Ubuntu hardware enablement stack?

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

This will give you a 4.15 kernel and update the xserver. More details to be found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: It turns out the Ubuntu hardware enablement stack not only fails to boot, but also messed up the EFI/GRUB boot configuration.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I have used it often and have not experienced problems so far.